# What is the result if we try to subtract a number from a character in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays

I had a test and the code I had given was subtracting an integer from each character of an array in a loop and I had to write output of that.

```
arr[] = "Hello_World"

for (int i=0; i< str.length; i++)
{
    if (i%2 == 0)
    {
       arr[i] = arr[i] + 2;
    }
    else
    {
       arr[i] = arr[i] - 2;
    }
}
```

So when we will add or subtract 2 to arr[i] that is let suppose "H" ,then what will be the result ?

Comment: `'H'` + 2 = `'J'` or 74, `'H'` - 2 = `'F'` or 70.  BTW a lot of that doesn't look like C++ code to me (`if []`, `str.length` (and there isn't even a `str`?)).

Comment: Characters are numbers - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii - but be careful of underflow/overflow.

Comment: sorry I had to write arr there. Anyway my point is clear now thanks for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, the first line was supposed to be

```
char arr[] = "Hello_World";
```

That creates an array named `arr` that holds values of type `char`. `char` is a numeric type. It does not hold characters, just numbers. On output, those numbers are used to look up character glyphs according to the current character encoding. Similarly, when interpreting `"Hello_World"`, the compiler uses the compile-time character encoding to translate those characters into numeric values that get stored in `arr`.

So, what happens when you change those values is simply that the values change. When you write that string to the console (`std::cout << arr << '\n';`), the output operation translates those numbers into characters according to the current character encoding.

On almost all systems, the character encoding is ASCII, and as long as you stay in the range of values that represent letters, you'll get what you expect: `'H' + 2` is `'J'`, etc. But there are characters encodings for which this is not always true. So be a bit careful when you do this sort of thing. You might be introducing a subtle non-portability.

Comment: Well explained. Thanks !!

Answer (score -1):

The output to that code would be "Jcnjq]Ymtjd"
+2/-2 is added/subtracted to the ASCII value of each character depending on the if condition. Like 'H'+ 2 = 'J' because ascii value of H=72 ; 72+2=74=>'J'
That isn't c++ syntax tho.

Comment: Not necessarily. There are systems that do not use ASCII. EBCDIC, in particular has a gap in the numeric values for letters.