# How to change each specific char to an int in C++

Tags: c++, string, casting, integer

It might be a really dumb question, but I have tried to look it up, and have googled a bunch, but still can't figure out an easy way...

In C++, saying that `using namespace std;`:

```
int main()
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0);
    cin.tie(0);

    String N;

    cin >> N;
}
```

When user input is `123`, `N` will be `"123"`.

How do I cast `'1'` to int `1`, and `'2'` to int `2`, and `'3'` to int `3`?

I cannot use `%`.

It would be awesome if I were to use an index approach in the string.

I would like to have a function that receives `N` and its index as parameters. For instance:

```
int func(string N, int curr_ind)
{
   // change curr_ind of N to a single int
   // for instance, "123" and 1, it would return 2.
}
```

Comment: `String N;` - what is `String`? Is `ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0); cin.tie(0);` really necessary to show whatever it is that you want to show?

Comment: Wouldn't `return (N[curr_ind] - '0');` work?

Comment: _" I cannot use %"_ - why?

Comment: "I cannot use %" probably means "My professor wants me to use a loop over the `char` of the `string` and not `%10` and `/10` on an `int`"

Answer (score 2):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int get_digit_from_string(const std::string&s, int idx) {
  return static_cast<int>(s[idx] - '0');
}

int main() {
  std::string num{"12345"};

  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < num.length(); ++i) {
    std::cout << get_digit_from_string(num, i) << '\n';
  }
}
```

Just get the character at the index, subtract `'0'`, and cast to `int`.

The subtraction is necessary, otherwise the character of a digit will be cast to the ASCII value of that character. The ASCII value of `'0'` is `48`.

Output:

```
❯ ./a.out 
1
2
3
4
5
```

Now, just for fun, let's say you need frequent access to these digits. Ideally, you'd just do the conversion all at once and have these `int`s available to you. Here's one way of doing that (requires C++20):

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> get_digits_from_string(const std::string& s) {
  std::vector<int> v;
  std::ranges::transform(s, std::back_inserter(v),
                         [](auto c) { return static_cast<int>(c - '0'); });

  return v;
}

int main() {
  std::string num{"12345"};
  std::vector<int> digits = get_digits_from_string(num);

  for (auto i : digits) {
    std::cout << i << '\n';
  }
}
```

We use the string to create a `std::vector` where each element is an `int` of the individual characters. I can then access the vector and get whatever digit I need easily.

Comment: Obligatory reminder to those in the future that ASCII encoding is not guaranteed. This has no bearing on the meat of the answer because contiguous and ascending digits are guaranteed.

Comment: Also, a remainder, always validate user input! Make sure the input actually contains numeric digits before trying to convert them.

Comment: In `return static_cast<int>(s[idx] - '0')`, what is the reason for the cast? The type of `s[idx] - '0'` is already `int` (unless `sizeof(char) == sizeof(int)` and `char` is unsigned).

Comment: Re: "the character of a digit will be cast" no, not unless you write a cast. A cast is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion. The **value** in `s[idx]` will be the encoded value of the digit; the actual value depends on the character encoding (usually ASCII these days) and the character being represented.

Comment: @user4581301 • the language does require that the characters `'0'` to `'9'` are incrementally increasing and in order.  If the underlying encoding differs (e.g., DS9K's character encoding), the compiler has to compensate.

Comment: @PeteBecker I prefer to be explicit. And your second comment just seems to be the remainder of the sentence you quoted with extra steps.

Comment: @sweenish -- I wouldn't write `int x = static_cast<int>(1 + 1);`; that's far too explicit. <g>

Comment: @sweenish -- as to my second comment, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68613100/what-is-the-result-if-we-try-to-subtract-a-number-from-a-character-in-c/68613708#68613708). `char` is a numeric type; it holds a value. The **interpretation** of that value depends on how it's used; on output it's typically translated into a character, but it's still just a value. C++ doesn't have a "character" type. The mapping between stored values and characters is a **convention**, enforced by the compiler when you use character constants and by the runtime when you write output.

Comment: I still don't see an issue. You are fine with just the function return for an implicit conversion, I'm not.

Comment: And just to be clear, I understand what you're saying. I also think it's the smallest nit to be picking. C++ has a character type, it's `char`. What it is under the hood is good information to know, but treating the type purely as its 'underlying' type is normally a bad idea. If we were discussing a custom class that for all intents and purposes just wrapped and behaved like its underlying type with one or two key differences, we'd be calling out non explicit converting constructors.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string input;
    std::cin >> input;

    // allocate int array for every character in input
    int* value = new int[input.size()];

    for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); ++i)
    {
        std::string t(1, input[i]);
        value[i] = atoi(t.c_str());
    }

    // print int array
    for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << value[i] << std::endl;
    }

    delete[] value;
}
```

Output:

```
x64/Debug/H1.exe
123
1
2
3
```

Comment: Better to use `std::vector` instead of `new[]`

Comment: std::vector, of course. It's already late - brain only at 80% :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int func(string N, int curr_ind)
{
   return static_cast<int>(N[curr_ind]-'0');
}
```

Since the ASCII representation of consecutive digits differs by one, all you need to do to convert a character (`char c;`) representing a digit to the corresponding integer is: `c-'0'`